# How to change the temperature of sub-circuits in LTSPICE

Tags: temperature, spice, ltspice, pspice, subcircuit

I have subcircuits of a solar cell (resistors and diodes) in LTSPICE. I want to connect the solar cells (sub-circuits) together. However, each solar cell has a different temperature. I can set the temperature of the program with `.Temp` but how can I change the temperature of each sub-circuit separately.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few ways.

You can add it to the actual model you are using as a final parameter or use the component dialog box:

[image: Setting the temperature of a component]

To get this dialog for anything that has a .model statement, use CTRL + right click.

If you are adding the temperature command within the SPICE listing, it needs the format of "temp=xx"; no dot required. The listing you show has omitted the '='.

Comment: Dear Peter, thank you for your answer. I tried this method but it does not work (why?).
I have uploaded the picture of the circuit and netlist in addition to the change you mentioned.
Since I have diodes in my model, by changing the temperature, I expect to have reduction in my open-circuit voltage. However, the open-circuit voltage does not change. Is there any mistakes there?
I add the code picture to the main question.
Greets and thanks in advance

Comment: The answer has been updated with the required syntax for embedding within a .subckt statement.

Comment: Dear Peter
thanks for your answer. 
The .temp command is for the total circuit and the dialog that you see beside the commands is for the sub-circuit. I have written it without dot (.).

Comment: Even without using .temp command, the results do not change.